# Creating a new column in Pandas DataFrame by splitting another column twice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
                          NAME
0  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-08.csv
1  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-09.csv
2  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-10.csv
3  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-11.csv
4  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-12.csv
5  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-13.csv
```

Here is the code to create it:

```
rows = ['this_is_a_sample_2017-09-08','this_is_a_sample_2017-09-09','this_is_a_sample_2017-09-10','this_is_a_sample_2017-09-11','this_is_a_sample_2017-09-12','this_is_a_sample_2017-09-13']
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = ['NAME'])
```

I want a new column which has only the date part of the name in it. Resulting DataFrame would look  like this:

```
                          NAME       DATE
0  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-08.csv   2017-09-08
1  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-09.csv   2017-09-09
2  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-10.csv   2017-09-10
3  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-11.csv   2017-09-11
4  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-12.csv   2017-09-12
```

I tried the following:

```
df['DATE'] = df.NAME.str.split(".")[0].split('_')[-1]
```

I thought I could split the column twice and fetch the date from the list, however when I index it using `[0]` it selects the value in the first row, which is a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use .str accessor to select the index over the series i.e

```
 df['Date'] =  df['NAME'].str.split(".").str[0].str.split('_').str[-1]
```

```
                         NAME        Date
0  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-08  2017-09-08
1  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-09  2017-09-09
2  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-10  2017-09-10
3  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-11  2017-09-11
4  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-12  2017-09-12
5  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-13  2017-09-13
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use regex

```
df['Date'] = df['NAME'].str.extract('.*?_(\d+-\d+-\d+).csv', expand = False)


    NAME                            Date
0   this_is_a_sample_2017-09-08.csv 2017-09-08
1   this_is_a_sample_2017-09-09.csv 2017-09-09
2   this_is_a_sample_2017-09-10.csv 2017-09-10
3   this_is_a_sample_2017-09-11.csv 2017-09-11
4   this_is_a_sample_2017-09-12.csv 2017-09-12
5   this_is_a_sample_2017-09-13.csv 2017-09-13
```

Or as @Evan suggested, use

```
df['Date'] = df['NAME'].str.extract('([\d-]+)', expand = False)
```

Comment: Your regex could be simplified to `'([\d-]+)'`

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you have "split('.')," all you really need is this:

```
df['DATE'] = df['NAME'].str.split('_').str[-1]

                          NAME        DATE
0  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-08  2017-09-08
1  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-09  2017-09-09
2  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-10  2017-09-10
3  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-11  2017-09-11
4  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-12  2017-09-12
5  this_is_a_sample_2017-09-13  2017-09-13
```

Comment: I missed the extension when I set up the question. There is a ".csv" at the end of every row value! I edited my question or reflect this, thanks for pointing it out!